# Github Laravel workflow getting invalid JSON from routes

Tags: php, laravel, github, phpunit, github-actions

For the automated testing of a *laravel API* I am using the 'laravel' action on github actions, the one made by github actions.
The tests keep failing telling me *invalid JSON returned from route*, *expected response code 200 but got 500, cannot read property status on null* and *cannot find in json*

I'm using laravel sanctum. Could it be a csrf-token problem?

My action yml: https://gist.github.com/I2EJeffrey/77df8faac1b0f86623e2e4449f98d858

My response function:

```
     * success response method.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function sendResponse($result, $message, $code = 200)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => $result, // result is most often one or 2 arrays
            'message' => $message,
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```

Example test:

```
    public function testSuccessfullyCreateAccommodationType()
    {
        $this->login(); // Login function that lots of tests need.

        $response = $this->postJson('/api/v5/accommodations/1/types', ['accommodation_name'=>$this->createName()]);

        $response
        ->assertJsonFragment(['success' => true])
        ->assertJsonStructure(['success', 'data' => 
        [], 'message']); // The array is filled with keys
    }
```

EDIT: 2 errors that I got by using `withoutExceptionHandling`: https://gist.github.com/I2EJeffrey/da23bfbdf5fba155456bd799a34f6276

EDIT 2: I also get the following warning: `TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.`

EDIT 3: The client model and the client seeder. Whenever I run the tests a mysql docker container starts that gets a db migrated and seeded into it:
https://gist.github.com/I2EJeffrey/39c779df217c9a75a7569f6fa3957d77
https://gist.github.com/I2EJeffrey/41cbbdba8025d38547059d3a6f4d4392

Comment: You need to show the errors as there is no `status` (property) reading in your code. There is something else going on. You can also use `$this->withouthExceptionHandling();`, so it stop saying `expected 200 but returned 500`, you will literally get the exception.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks for your comment, I didn't know that was a thing. I've added a link to the gist with the exceptions to the question. I don't think it'll be much help though as it just says the same thing.

Comment: So, checking the gists, I see the first error is happening in `/home/runner/work/system-backend/backend-api/src/laravel/app/Models/ClientModels/Client.php:46`, can you share that part?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Updates question again. It's weird that its on that part since "locked" is default 0 and i set status to 20 in seeder.

Comment: The issue is that `$client` is `null`, see that you are doing `self::find($client_id);`, that is going to return a `Client` instance or `null` if not found. Because you did not share who is calling `isActive` with what `$client_id`, I would check if I have the right `$client_id` passed because that is the issue

Comment: Thanks for the help @matiaslauriti due to your last comment I've been able to find out what was wrong! I hope github adds the option to view the database that gets created in my workflow sometime, that would've been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the DB didn't get seeded due to not having added `$this->call(ClientSeeder::class);` to the DatabaseSeeder. Which caused the routes to return null and thus wrong json.